# POSTFIX smtpd relay depending on sender

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am using Postfix on a server `mx1.domain1.com` to relay e-mails for `domain1.com` as well as other domains, `domain2.net`, and `domain3.org`, which are hosted on the server (`domain1.com`). In addition, `mx1.domain1.com` also relays e-mails on behalf of a different server (`offsite.domain1.com`). This works all great.

My `main.cf` looks like this:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit

myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mx1.domain1.com, domain1.com, localhost

virtual_alias_domains = domain2.net, domain3.org
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Here is my `/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders`

```
#envelope sender        owners (SASL login names)
@domain1.com        user1
@offisite.domain1.com   user1
@domain2.net            user1, user2
@domain3.org        user1, user3
```

Here is my `/etc/postfix/virtual`

```
postmaster@domain1.com  username1
e-mail@domain1.com  username2
```

What I want to achieve is the following.
I want to use the POSTFIX instance on mx1.domain1.com to relay a message for `domain4.ca` but use the SMTP server of `domain4.ca`, for which I have an authentication.

I tried to achieve this by amending my `main.cf` with this:

```
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
relayhost =
relay_domains = domain4.ca
```

However, no matter what I do, I get the following error:

```
Dec 12 18:24:48 vserver-fra01 postfix/smtps/smtpd[146379]: connect from unknown[1.2.3.4]
Dec 12 18:24:48 vserver-fra01 postfix/smtps/smtpd[146379]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[1.2.3.4]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256
Dec 12 18:24:49 mx1 postfix/smtps/smtpd[146379]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[1.2.3.4]: 553 5.7.1 <e-mail@domain4.ca>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user xyz; from=< e-mail@domain4.ca > to=<addressee@organization.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[2.3.4.5]>
Dec 12 18:24:49 mx1 postfix/smtps/smtpd[146379]: lost connection after RCPT from unknown[1.2.3.4]
Dec 12 18:24:49 mx1 postfix/smtps/smtpd[146379]: disconnect from unknown[1.2.3.4] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 commands=3/4
```

How can I configure POSTFIX on `mx1.domain1.com` to relay for `domain4.ca` and use the SMTP server for `domain4.ca`?

**SOLUTION:**

I had overlooked a line in the `master.cf`, which "governed" who was allowed to use the SMTP service; it referenced to `/etc/postfix/virtual`.

```
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname,localhost
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

So, the solution was to add `domain4.ca` into the `/etc/postfix/virtual` table.

```
e-mail@domain4.ca   username1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use transport maps

1. `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport` in main.cf
2. Create a file for example /etc/postfix/transport
   With the following content
   `domain4.ca    [smtp.domain4.ca]:587` (one line)
3. `postmap /etc/postfix/transport`
4. Reload postfix

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestion and tried that, but it didn't work. The error was related to a restriction in my master.cf file.

Comment: Please edit your post and post the full error and your main.cf redacted